# HTML to show a SVG as a link to another page

Tags: html

I'm trying to show an SVG, which, when clicked, links to another page. Here is what I tried:

```
<a href="foo.html">
  <embed src="something.svg" />
</a>
```

What is the preferred method for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the embed tag. Instead use an `<img>` tag and the anchor should work just fine.